# Ranking computed variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using the `Cigarette` dataset from the `Ecdat` package. I need to find the median annual rank of number of packs/capita sold between 1985 and 1995. As well as the lowest, whereby higher rank is defined as having a grater number of packs/capita.

I have tried to filter based on year and compute a median packs variable using median(packpc) and arrange by that mutated variable but continue to get error messages.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is "the median annual rank"?  If you have 100 observations and rank them on anything, the median is 50.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `summarize`:

```
library(Ecdat)
library(dplyr)
Cigarette %>% 
  filter(year>=1985, year<=1995) %>% 
  summarise(min=min(packpc), median=median(packpc), max=max(packpc))
#>       min   median     max
#> 1 49.2722 105.9096 197.994
```

As you put the `dplyr` tag to this question, you might want to check out tutorials on this package.

PS: If this is your homework, you should state it clearly so we don't just give out the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the idea is to get the states' ranks for each year and then find the median and minimum of those ranks over the years.

Since the dataset only includes years 1985 to 1995, there is no need for `filter`ing.

So I came up with this rather ugly solution:

```
ranks_perYear <- aggregate(packpc ~ year, Cigarette, rank)$packpc
colnames(ranks_perYear) <- levels(Cigarette$state)
medianRank <- apply(ranks_perYear, 2, median)
minRank <- apply(ranks_perYear, 2, min)
```

I am actually not entirely sure whether the states are assigned correctly here. Maybe the dataset has to be sorted by state (e.g., `dplyr::arrange(Cigarette, state)`) beforehand.